# How to rerender parent component buttons React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have deeply nested JSON file with names of buttons as four level buttons.

Every button in first level need to have a **onClick** function which toggles nested component with second Level buttons and the flow for all levels is described below:

1. I tried to create all button levels in single component.
2. I also tried to Nest component for every level.
3. I tried to pass **onClick** function as a prop to child component and make a callback to change the parent.

**Main Issue at point number 3:**

This is working but only in console log, I cannot render new values (but I have new values in console.log)

What correction do I need to perform?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow Zarko! Instead of describing your code, you can include the code directly in the question. It will be hard for anyone to help you otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for advice @Tholle, but the code is too big, also JSON is large, it's is hard to explain what is what :D. I just need help whit what kind of technique to approach to this problem. I need child component button (which is rendered by parrent) to have a click function which rerender the parent again.

Comment: If it is hard to explain what you want, it will also be hard for someone to adequately help you. Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and explain what it is you are having trouble with more precisely.

Comment: i will try to make it in code, thanks